# Regex pattern Alphanumeric and dollar sign

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I would like to know how I set a regex pattern for aphanumeric and dollar sign.
Except for dollar sign, it does not accept any other special characters.

Here are examples...

The pattern should be okay with ....

```
 hahah
 hohho
 hihihi
 $hahah
 hahah I will get $100 for this
```

The pattern should be sad with ....

```
 hi James. 
 #fdasfdas
 run!
```

Any idea?

so you want it to require a '$' symbol somewhere in the string? – yes.

Do you want to allow spaces also? - yes

please add more details, unless the below answer is what you are looking for. Currently this isn't a clear question. – sorry I just got back to my machine.

```
    public static bool IsAlphanumericCharactersAndDollarSign(string str)
{
    if (str == null) return false;
    Regex rg = new Regex(@"/[a-zA-z0-9\s\$]*/");

    return rg.IsMatch(str);
}
```

Comment: so you want it to require a '$' symbol somewhere in the string?

Comment: Do you want to allow spaces also?

Comment: please add more details, unless the below answer is what you are looking for.  Currently this isn't a clear question.

Comment: sorry guys :/ I just got back to my machine.

Comment: Why can't you attempt to accomplish this code first?

Comment: the pattern is not working. :(

Comment: @user1713153: *How* is it not working?

Answer (score 2):

Pattern for this: `/[a-zA-z0-9\s\$]*/` match alphanumeric, spaces and $ sign 0 or more times

This is PCRE compliant, but in perl for example you need to escape the `$` with `\$`

Comment: hmm... not working. it even hates alphabets.

Comment: Can you paste your code

Comment: <input  data-val-regex="Sorry, the challenge reward cannot contain any special characters other than $." data-val-regex-pattern="/[a-zA-z0-9\s\$]*/" type="text" value="">

Comment: the data attribute takes a regex pattern to validate an input value.

Comment: Remove the / slashes and try

Comment: I am not sure for js the pattern should have a different format or not

Comment: What js library are you using

Comment: I have a custom library. but mostly using jQuery

Comment: hmmm... now it allows everything.

Comment: Without posting your code we can't debug this

Comment: hmm... actually something went wrong. it is not working. I wrote test cases to test